# extract data from json file using python

Tags: python, json

I have this json file.

```
{
  "entityId": "PROCESS_1234",
  "displayName": "Windows System",
  "firstSeenTms": 1619147697131,
  "lastSeenTms": 1653317760000,
  "properties": {
    "detectedName": "Windows System",
    "bitness": "32",
    "metadata": [],
    "awsNameTag": "Windows System",
    "softwareTechnologies": [
      {
        "type": "WINDOWS_SYSTEM"
      }
    ],
    "processType": "WINDOWS_SYSTEM"
    
    
  }
  
}
```

I need to extract entityId": "PROCESS_1234" and "properties": {
"detectedName": "Windows System" as a data frame. The data frame needs to look like this:

```
entityId        detectedName
PROCESS_1234    Windows System
```

I have tried this:

```
print(resp2['entityId']['properties'][0]['detectedName'])
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-09b87f04b95e> in <module>
----> 1 print(resp2['entityId']['properties'][0]['detectedName'])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: there's a trailing ] on your json, below processType

Comment: If you select `entityId`, the value is now `"PROCESS_1234"` so when you select "property" it is not valid for strings

Comment: @Fed_Dragon I need to build a data frame this json

Answer (score 2):

To extract `entityId`, do:

```
print(resp2['entityId'])
```

To extract `detectedName`, do:

```
print(resp2['properties']['detectedName'])
```

Comment: print needs to print out entityId and detectedName in one line not different print statements

Comment: @user1471980 Do `print(resp2['entityId'], resp2['properties']['detectedName'])`

Answer (score 0):

this error occur when you pass a string value

print(resp2[0][1])
try like this.

Answer (score 0):

The program

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
  "entityId": "PROCESS_1234",
  "displayName": "Windows System",
  "firstSeenTms": 1619147697131,
  "lastSeenTms": 1653317760000,
  "properties": {
    "detectedName": "Windows System",
    "bitness": "32",
    "metadata": [],
    "awsNameTag": "Windows System",
    "softwareTechnologies": [
      {
        "type": "WINDOWS_SYSTEM"
      }
    ],
    "processType": "WINDOWS_SYSTEM"
  }
}

rows = [(data['entityId'], data['properties']['detectedName'])]
x = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=['entityId', 'detectedName'])
print(x)
```

The output

```
bash-5.1$ python3 c.py
       entityId    detectedName
0  PROCESS_1234  Windows System
```